# Restoring MySQL from localhost to live server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, remote-access

I am developing a web application in CodeIgniter and MySQL.

I need to set up a function to update data in MySQL in my local server when there is no internet connection and later switch to live server when the connections are available, restore the locally saved data into live database as well.

(There may be clients 1) at remote location who have poor internet connectivity which I need this idea for and 2) the other who can add data directly to the live server).

Is there any mechanism to get this done?

Comment: See I have not done till yet. But, i can suggest. 
Keep 2 database connection file. First for local database and,second for your server database.

1) Keep all data locally. For example (Morning 9- Night 9). After that, keep one button namely 'Submit to server'. When you click that button, give link reference to one page and in that page transfer all data from localhost to server. How, using locally database name to server database name. Meanwhile delete also locally database. 

Use while loop for transferring data.

Comment: Your concept is good for single user system, what if there is a case of multiple users logged in and are adding data to the system? saving whole database locally and updating it to live server later on may override the data entered by simultaneous users...

Comment: No Mr Saw. Each user will have there separate database. 
Like DB1, DB2.... So what is the problem. User having DB1 will send to server database. User having DB2 will also send to Server Database

Comment: yeah but if user X updates the database locally and user Y does it at the same time with their own database and at the time they want to push the local data to live server the final database needs to have both of the data from X and Y? is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Possible. Logic is correct. Implementation will be little more tricky. 
It was just a suggestion. If you get more appropriate answer, please let me know. Thanku.

Comment: ok Thanks, lets see if i get any other answers more appropriate ones..:)

Comment: How about Replication?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Answer (score 3):

Mysql Database Replication

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves). Replication is asynchronous - slaves need not be connected permanently to receive updates from the master. This means that updates can occur over long-distance connections and even over temporary or intermittent connections such as a dial-up service. Depending on the configuration, you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected tables within a database.